# QGIS 3.22 does not display Google Earth after added as a XYZ tile

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, google-earth

I am new to QGIS, I need to add Google Earth as an XYZ tile, I did this by clicking it, then hitting new connection then using the Google Earth link, and hitting okay. I then tried to view it but it does not display anything. I tried asking it to zoom into layers as that resolved a previous issue I had. Unsure where to go from here. This is the link I used: [http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)  this is for a lab I am working on so it was given to me.

[image]

EDIT: This is what shows when I open the Logs [image]

EDIT: I noticed when I hover my mouse over the blank screen, coordinates will show at the bottom of the screen indicating that it is working I just cannot see it.
[image]

Comment: What you did looks valid, I get a Sat view with your setup. Do you see anything unexpected if you open the Logs (icon at the bottom right of the QGIS window)

Comment: I usually use Google Earth via the Quick Map Services plugin value added pack, but my xyz tile is slightly different from yours.  Here's mine: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D